# Unidentifiable malware

Tags: firefox, malware

For the past few weeks whenever I open any web browser the url bar says `https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/amazo-irland/json2/urls/sRCH2.html` then redirects me to either search.ask.com or alarabeyes.com.

Same thing happens when I open a new tab. I ran 2 full scans with windows defender and it says there is no problem. My computer and internet have been very sluggish for the past few weeks and I assume it is because of this.

Whenever I try to open a page 50% it says `Connection has been reset` and I need to refresh the page. I can't play a YouTube video on anything over 240p because the internet is too bad. Sometimes when I open any page there are ads on the bottom left and bottom right. I clicked one of them and the url of the page said `https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/amazo-irland/json2/urls/sRCH2.html` then redirected me to the random ad website. Please help me...

Comment: I checked, it's not that.

Comment: see the extensions part on chrome or addons on mozilla, they hide on that. try malware remover they hunt this down. antivirus is more for system protection

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, viruses or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc)

Comment: You might check if your DNS server setting was changed. A rogue server could send you anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Check for any new extension installed in browser. In chrome if you list with developer mode option enabled you will get ID for the particular extension and search for that ID in your machine. sometimes it will be a hidden file. find it and delete including the folder

Check registry also for the particular ID, if found delete it

Check the browser short cut, by right clicking the bowser short cut and select properties. In properties look at the target (In my case "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"), make sure that there is nothing other than the path to the executable is present. If found any other strings then simply delete it.

Check for those newly installed third party software in your programs list that was not installed by you. if any new installations is noticed; locate their folder, uninstall it and remove all left overs.

In Chrome browser, goto chrome://settings, click on Advanced settings at bottom and click Reset settings button

In Mozilla firefox, goto Help > Troubleshooting Information and click Refresh Firefox button.

Restart machine and check your browser.

Comment: I just mentioned the same thing in my answer, without the addition of the shortcut and registry.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use Toolbar Cleaner.
Remove all  the unwanted installed toolbars found on your browser.
Maybe this solve the issue.
Link : http://download.cnet.com/Toolbar-Cleaner/3000-2094_4-75439821.html

Comment: I tried Toolbar Cleaner it didn't work. It says "nothing was found" under Firefox.

Comment: here is not allowed to use brands but i suggest malwarebytes, i call him every time i get this issues. and if your browser is corrupted already try a browser reset or a clean install

Answer (score -1):

steps before proceeding.

**Check your installed plugins and extensions and look for new ones that have appeared and delete them.**

Run IOBit Uninstaller, look for recently installed programs and uninstall any new programs that you haven't installed yourself, then delete all the files and registry it finds in the leftover scan.

Works everytime something weird happens to my browser.